# QAF Reports are not populated in dashboard.htm

Tags: qaf

1. Got the latest code here: https://github.com/infostretch/qaf-report.
2. Extracted dashboard directory & dashboard.htm to the project root directory.
3. Ran QAF tests.
4. Opened dashboard.htm during test run & also after test run.
5. Tried to open dashboard.htm in Google Chrome, Firefox & Safari after giving permissions to access local files. But Dashboard.htm did not load anything. A spinning icon is displayed continously even after several minutes.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing reports locally as file protocol, browser may have restriction to access local files. In such case follow the steps to allow local file access from file for the browser you are using.

**Firefox:**

```
go to about:config
set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy:false.
```

**Safari:**

```
Click on the Develop menu in the menu bar.
Select Disable Local File Restrictions.
```

If develop menu is not available, Click on the Edit > Preferences > Advanced tab. Check "Show Develop menu in the menu bar.
**chrome:**

```
Close down your Chrome browser (make sure you close all instances if you have multiple windows open)
Go to Run and type the following command: chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-file.
Hit enter.
```

Reference from [local-report-access](https://github.com/infostretch/qaf-report#local-report-access)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give more clarity by making little corrections to the existing steps mentioned here: 
https://github.com/infostretch/qaf-report#local-report-access

When you are opening report "dashboard.htm" from local file system, your browser may have local file access restrictions.

In that case, you can do following setings:

- Firefox:

  1. Enter "about:config" in the browser url field & click on the button "Accept the Risk & Continue".
  2. In the "search preference name" field, enter "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" & click Enter & click on the toggle button towards the right to set it FALSE.
- Safari:

  1. Click on the Develop menu in the menu bar.
  2. Select Disable Local File Restrictions.

If develop menu is not available, 
1. Click on the Safari > Preferences > Advanced tab(in MAC, Safari > Preferences > Advanced tab). 
2. Check "Show Develop menu in the menu bar.

- Chrome:
- In Windows PC:

  1. Close down your Chrome browser (make sure you close all instances if you have multiple windows open)
  2. Go to Run and type the following command: chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-file.
- In MAC

  1. Open your terminal anywhere, make sure Google Chrome is currently not running, copy paste this line and hit enter:

open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: I followed the steps for Chrome in Windows PC, but still 'dashboard.htm' is blank.